# Are real numbers enough to solve simpler exponential equations such as $2^x=5$, $(1/e)^x=3$, and $\pi^x=e$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, exponential-function, real-numbers

How to prove that solutions of simpler exponential equations (*) are real numbers?

In other words, how to prove that set of real numbers is *enough* to solve something like $2^x = 5,$ or $(\frac{1}{e})^x = 3$ or even $\pi^{x} = e$?

(*) Assumption is that base is not something like $e^{\sqrt{2}}, e^{\pi}, 2^{\frac{1}{2}},$ (#) so only "given" (computed in some way) indeed real? Also, inverse question: How to prove that this numbers (#) are real?

Graphically: how to prove that exponential function $f(x) = e^x$ for $x \in (- \infty, + \infty)$ "picks up" all the real values?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "are real numbers enough". There is a real solution to your first exponential equation, but in addition to your real solution, there are also many complex solutions. So what is meant by "enough"?

Comment: If $1\ne a>0$ and $b>0$, then $a^x=b$ has the solution $x=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$

Comment: Well, if $a\neq 1$ is a positive real number, then $x\mapsto a^x$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$ and has the range $(0,\infty)$. Although the actual proof depends on how we realize $a^x$ (there are basically two major approaches, extending exponential of rational exponent to $\mathbb{R}$ or using calculus), the proof is not supposed to be hard in any cases.

Comment: @imranfat Maybe the question should be interpreted as "How to prove that (Real)^(Real) is a real number?"

Comment: You would need strong restriction on your expressions.  $x^2=-1$ doesn't have  a real solution.

Comment: The word "simpler" is also ambiguous. The equation $2^x=-5$ does not even have a real solution

Comment: @Quillo Consider $(-1)^{1/2}$.

Comment: $1^x=2$ has no real solution.

Comment: intermediate value theorem

Comment: Couldn't we just prove that $\{n^m \in \mathbb{R} \mid n \in \mathbb{R}, m \in \mathbb{R}\}$, meaning that the real numbers are an inclusive ring?

Comment: @orlp I didn't write it for brevity but bf course the base is positive, otherwise the question is trivial. Same for the above comment of Jaden Lee $(n>0)$, which is the formal version of what I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First recall that the map
\begin{align*}
\exp &: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)
\end{align*}
is a bijection (you can prove this by e.g., proving that $\exp$ is continuous, strictly increasing (this gives injective), unbounded, and obtains arbitrarily small positive values - then invoke the intermediate value theorem (this gives surjective)). In particular $\exp(x) = r$ has a unique real solution whenever $r \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, which we call $\log(r)$.

By definition, whenever $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ we have
$$\alpha^x = \exp (\log(\alpha) x)$$

which defines a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ whenever $\log(\alpha) \neq 0$ - i.e., when $\alpha \neq 1$ (since then it is a composition of bijections).

This also gives a solution to your second question, we know that $\exp(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ whenever $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\log(\alpha) \in \mathbb{R}$ exists whenever $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ we have $\alpha^x = \exp(\log(\alpha)x) \in \mathbb{R}$ whenever $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that this question is much more subtle when $\alpha < 0$ since we must choose our $\log$'s etc. But for sure $(-1)^{1/2} \notin \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, your equations will also have complex solutions - so we do not have uniqueness if we extend our view to $\mathbb{C}$. The moral being - $\log$ is not well behaved in $\mathbb{C}$ so your question turns out to be a subtle one if we allow $\mathbb{C}$ to be involved.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know source which proves that exp function is continuous, strictly increasing and obtains arbitarely small values? Another question: if exp can be arbitarely small and stricly increases how that proves anything. For example, imagine that $e^x$ is for $x = 0$ equal to $1,$ for $x = 1$ is $1.1,$ for $x = 2$ is $1.11,$ etc.Then, when $x \rightarrow \infty,$ $e^x$ would be $1.1111...$ so maybe there have to be more conditions..

Comment: @1b3b yes that is a good point, I meant to say unbounded also - I have updated my answer. I can't think of a reference off the top of my head, but it is not too difficult to show from, say, the power series definition.

Comment: Thanks again, I will search for the proof

Comment: Correct, but in the first line you are already saying everything, namely $ exp : \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty) $. A deeper interpretation of the OP question would be to show that, given the axiomatic construction of the reals, the exp operation gives a (positive) real number.

Comment: @Quillo, yes for sure - the rest is merely an overview of why that is enough. In my original answer I was somewhat concerned that that would be talking over OP's head, so I avoided complete rigor.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the equations you mention actually have complex solutions as well.

But in general, you may ask - given an equation, if I solve it using real methods - how do I know there are no other complex solutions? The answer is you cannot. Real numbers **are a subset of the complex numbers**, so you are actually working within a small subset of ${\mathbb{C}}$. You can, however, redefine your variable to be a complex variable and solve it using complex methods - and if you still end up with purely real solutions (that is, solutions with imaginary part ${=0}$), you can be sure those are indeed the only solutions (at least within the context of ${\mathbb{C}}$, anyways).

Now, asking how to tell if expressions like ${2^e}$ are real completely depends upon the definitions you use for these expressions. One definition for ${2^e}$ is to take a limit as ${n\rightarrow\infty}$ of ${2^{e_n}}$ - where ${e_n}$ is a sequence of real numbers converging to $e$, taking the principle root at each point in the sequence (by principle root, I mean for example taking ${2^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ as being ${\sqrt{2}}$). In this case, the expression, by definition, will intrinsically be real.